# Drop rows from Dask DataFrame where column count is not equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a CSV file which I want to normalize for SQL input. I want to drop every line, where's the column count not equal to a certain number within a row, this way I can ignore the bad lines, where column shift can happen. In the past, I used AWK to normalize this CSV dataset, but I want to implement this program in Python for easier parallelization other than GNU Parallel + AWK solution.

I tried the following codes to drop the lines:

```python
df.drop(df[df.count(axis='columns') != len(usecols)].index, inplace=True)
df = df[df.count(axis=1) == len(usecols)]
df = df[len(df.index) == len(usecols)]
```

None of this work, I need some help, Thank You!

**EDIT:**

- I'm working on a single CSV file on a single worker.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the awk script for reference:

```awk
{
    line = $0;
    # ...

    if (line ~ /^$/) next; # if line is blank, then remove it
    if (NF != 13) next; # if column count is not equal to 13, then remove it
}
```

Comment: dask.dataframes are just partitioned pandas dataframes - each partition needs to be a valid pandas dataframe, and all must have the same columns. so you can't do this with dask.dataframe. awk seems like a good pre-processing step to me :) otherwise you could use dask.delayed to pre-process each file, then read into a dataframe with `dask.dataframe.from_futures` (where each future would need to return a pandas dataframe with homogenous columns).

Comment: So if I want to keep the whole download and extracting process in my Python program, I need to call in AWK and use Gzip to extract, instead of Python? Then I will loose the possibility to directly stream files from S3 or HTTP to dataframe if I wanted to. Seems such a basic feature that pandas/dask can't handle, to know how many columns present in each line...

Comment: Can you add the `awk` command you are running? This will make it easier to construct the corresponding equivalent (or proxy) with dask/pandas.

Comment: `awk` lines are added from it's script file.

Comment: @Lanti: hmm, that's rather vague...

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not easy to understand. From the first statement it appears as if you are working with a single file, is that correct?

If so, if there are unnamed columns, then there will be an attempt by `pandas` (or `dask` via `pandas`) to 'fix' the structure by adding missing column labels with something like 'Untitled: 0'. Once that happens, it's easy to drop the misaligned rows by using something like:

```py
mask = df['Untitled: 0'].isna()
df = df[mask]
```

Edit: if there are rows that contain more entries than the number of defined columns, `pandas` will raise an error, saying it was not able to parse csv.

If, however, you are working with multiple csv files, then one option is to use `dask.delayed` to enforce compatible columns, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67497965/10693596) for further guidance.

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: Unable to parse string...` exception, because with the column shift, wrong `dtype` is used for the deleted column to the right. If I change dtype to silence the error, then I'm getting the following exception: `KeyError: 'Untitled: 0'`.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to post a separate answer, but it seems that this problem can be solved by passing `on_bad_lines` kwarg to `pandas.read_csv` (note: if you are using `pandas` version lower than `1.3.0`, you will need to use [`error_bad_lines`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)). Roughly, the code would look like this:

```py
from pandas import read_csv
df = read_csv('some_file.csv', on_bad_lines='warn')  # can use skip
```

Since `dask.dataframe` can pass kwargs to `pandas`, the above can also be written for `dask.dataframe`:

```py
from dask.dataframe import read_csv
df = read_csv('some_file.csv', on_bad_lines='warn')  # can use skip
```

With this, the imported csv will not reflect any lines that have more columns than expected based on the header (if there is a line with fewer elements than the number of columns, it will be included such that the missing values will be set to None).

Comment: I don't want to believe that I have so many issues with a single thing like this, but because this remote CSV dataset (which I don't have any control on) doesn't have a header line, `on_bad_lines` is broken for multiple reasons, the main one that is currently only working with more columns in a line: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/48728, the other issue is currently broken with `usecols`: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40049

Comment: Because of that, I will implement a simple `ZipFile` function which is reading the CSV line by line from ZIP, then immediately writing to a file with little preprocess, which is not CPU intensive (dropping empty and bad column count lines). This way I don't have to call `awk` as a subprocess.

Comment: Yeah, that's the reality, sometimes the data is broken in a way that the standard toolkit is not very useful.

Comment: I implemented the `ZipFile` function, until all bugs is fixed and feature requests are met from the community on Github.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a function which pre-processing the zipped CSV file for Pandas/Dask. These are not CPU/Memory heavy tasks, parallelization is not important in this step, so until there's no better way to do this, here we are. I'm adding a proper header for my pre-processed CSV file, too.

```python
with open(csv_filename, 'wt', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n') as file:
    join = '|'.join(usecols)
    file.write(f"{join}\n") # Adding header
    with ZipFile(destination) as z:
        with TextIOWrapper(z.open(f"{filename}.csv"), encoding='utf-8') as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line.strip() # Remove whitespace from line
                if line not in ['\n', '\r\n']: # Exclude empty line
                    array = line.split("|")
                    if len(array) == column_count:
                        del array[1:3] # Remove 1st, 2nd element
                        array = [s.strip() for s in array] # Strip whitespace
                        join = '|'.join(array)
                        file.write(f"{join}\n")
    # file.close()
```

PS.: This is not an answer for my original question, that's why I won't accept this.

Comment: Looks good! (it's not clear why removing 1/2 is necessary, but I trust this is specific to your situation)

Comment: Also, the last `file.close` is not necessary, context manager should close it automatically.